# Spawn server and wait, repeat on SIGHUP

Tags: bash, shell, signals

I'm trying to put together a script, that will start my (Node) development server, and whenever it receives a `SIGHUP` it should restart the server.

I've gotten as far as spawning the server, shutting it down and restarting the server on `SIGHUP`. But because I'm using `wait` in the spawning code, the `SIGHUP` handler never really returns, which leads to the signal never firing again.

Here's a stripped down version of my script:

```
SERVER_PID=""

start_server() {
    npm start &
    SERVER_PID=$!
    wait $SERVER_PID
}
terminate_server() {
    [ ! "xSERVER_PID" = "X" ] && kill -SIGTERM $SERVER_PID
    SERVER_PID=""
}
refresh_server() {
    terminate_server
    start_server
}

trap refresh_server SIGHUP
start_server
```

As I mentioned, it starts the server fine, and works as expected on the first `SIGHUP`, but since `refresh_server` never returns because of the `wait` in `start_server`, subsequent signals don't trigger any action.

For now, I've solved the issue by taking out the `wait` in `start_server`, and adding an infinite "while-true-sleep" loop at the bottom (after the initial call to `start_server`), but I'm sure there must be a better way to accomplish what I'm looking to achieve. Also, I dislike the delay in signal triggering  incurred from the sleep loop approach.

Comment: Typically, you use `init` (or `upstart` or `systemd` or whatever your OS uses) for this kind of service monitoring.

Comment: @chepner Naturally. This is for a dev-server running on my localhost. The SIGHUP'ing would be done by a watch+build script, upon changes in relevant parts of the code. Doing this by hand is starting to piss me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a while-true-wait loop?

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER_PID=""
SERVER_NAME="npm start"

start_server() {
    $SERVER_NAME &
    SERVER_PID=$!
    SERVER_ACTIVE=true
}
terminate_server() {
    [ ! "xSERVER_PID" = "X" ] && kill -SIGTERM $SERVER_PID
    SERVER_PID=""
}
refresh_server() {
    terminate_server
    start_server
}

trap refresh_server SIGHUP
start_server
while $SERVER_ACTIVE; do
  SERVER_ACTIVE=false
  wait $SERVER_PID
done
```

Some kind of waiting event loop is required, if it should be repeated, either explicitly in the script or somewhere hidden in bash

Comment: Very nice. I like this a lot.

Comment: @F.Hauri: That really does not matter, SERVER_PID is not "", when terminate is called, or you have other problems... And even if it were, callnig kill without a  parameter does not do any harm

Comment: Well the `$` is missing in my original snippet as well, and I wouldn't down vote for that anyway.

Comment: You'r wrong: Trap have to not execute but only to flag, in order to prevent bounces. This work but is not well

Comment: what does `[ ! "xSERVER_PID" = "X" ]` ?? You seem miss some `$` and maybe some tests...

Answer (score 0):

### Signal trap under bash

#### Return from exception

Like using signaling in other programmation languages, signal trapping could be done easely in a wrong way;

When using `trap` you have to **not** process your function **inside** the trap evaluation, but only set a *flag* that *main* program could check after end of *trap exception*, in order to make *exception execution* shorter as possible.

Especially, you have to **not** initiate a `fork` to a sub process at trap execution level!

#### A correct example

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_PID=""
CMD_TRAP=""

npm() { #Doing something that could be checked from external
    if [ "$1" ] && [ "$1" == "start" ] ;then
    while :;do
        date "+%s%N" >/tmp/dummyfile.txt
        sleep .333
          done
    fi
}

start_server() {
    npm start &
    SERVER_PID=$!
}
terminate_server() {
    [ "$SERVER_PID" ] && ps $SERVER_PID &>/dev/null && kill -TERM $SERVER_PID
    SERVER_PID=""
}
refresh_server() {
    terminate_server
    start_server
}

printf "for:\n   server restart, hit: 'kill -USR2 %d'\n" $$
printf "   server stop, hit: 'kill %d' (or Ctrl+C)\n" $$

trap 'CMD_TRAP=refresh' USR2 HUP
trap 'CMD_TRAP=terminate' TERM INT

start_server
while [ "$SERVER_PID" ];do 
    wait $SERVER_PID
    case "$CMD_TRAP" in
        refresh   ) refresh_server   ;;
        terminate ) terminate_server ;;
        *         ) refresh_server   ;;        # in case server just end.
      esac;
    CMD_TRAP=""
    [ "$SERVER_PID" ] && echo "LOOP." || echo "EXIT."
  done
```

#### Features

This demo script do:

- service will be started when script is started,
- service will be restarted if a `USR2` or a `HUP` signal is recieved,
- service will be restarted if it just finish or recieve any signal and
- service will be properly stopped is a `TERM` signal is recieved or

  - if `Ctrl-C` is hitted on console.
- exceptions is handled correctly (return immediately to main routine)
- no unwanted/unmanaged error messages

#### Outputs samples

> ***window1***

```
tty
/dev/pts/0
```

> ***window2***

```
ps --tty pts/0 fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2996 pts/0    Ss     0:01 bash
 5187 pts/0    S+     0:00  \_ bash
```

> ***window1***

```
./serverScript.sh 
for:
   server restart, hit: 'kill -USR2 11469'
   server stop, hit: 'kill 11469' (or Ctrl+C)
```

> ***window2***

```
ps --tty pts/0 fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2996 pts/0    Ss     0:01 bash
 5187 pts/0    S      0:00  \_ bash
11469 pts/0    S+     0:00      \_ /bin/bash ./servermon.sh
11470 pts/0    S+     0:00          \_ /bin/bash ./servermon.sh

cat /tmp/dummyfile.txt 
1361603642256133674

cat /tmp/dummyfile.txt 
1361603648712606114

    ps --tty pts/0 fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2996 pts/0    Ss     0:01 bash
 5187 pts/0    S      0:00  \_ bash
11469 pts/0    S+     0:00      \_ /bin/bash ./servermon.sh
11470 pts/0    S+     0:01          \_ /bin/bash ./servermon.sh
16814 pts/0    S+     0:00              \_ sleep .333

kill -USR2 11469
```

> ***window1***

```
LOOP.
```

> ***window2***

```
    ps --tty pts/0 fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2996 pts/0    Ss     0:01 bash
 5187 pts/0    S      0:00  \_ bash
11469 pts/0    S+     0:00      \_ /bin/bash ./servermon.sh
17152 pts/0    S+     0:00          \_ /bin/bash ./servermon.sh
17532 pts/0    S+     0:00              \_ sleep .333

cat /tmp/dummyfile.txt
1361604208069564188
cat /tmp/dummyfile.txt
1361604209103660589

kill -USR2 11469
```

> ***window1***

```
LOOP.
```

> ***window2***

```
cat /tmp/dummyfile.txt
1361604278583723517

cat /tmp/dummyfile.txt
1361604279605292149

kill 11469
```

> ***window1***

```
EXIT.
$
```

Window 1 terminate loop **and** server sub process.

> ***window1***

```
./serverScript.sh 
for:
   server restart, hit: 'kill -USR2 19232'
   server stop, hit: 'kill 19232' (or Ctrl+C)
```

Then if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed:

> ***window1***

```
^CEXIT.
$
```

> ***window2***

```
ps --tty pts/0 fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2996 pts/0    Ss     0:01 bash
 5187 pts/0    S+     0:00  \_ bash
```

#### Explanation

Exception could not be stacked. So while an exception is executed another interrupt could be ignored:

This could become important if for sample, your `refresh_server()` function have to compress and rotate some logs before restarting server:

```
refresh_server() {
    terminate_server
    lockedfilename=-$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S-$$)
    mv /srv/logfile /srv/logfile-$lockedfilename
    gzip /srv/logfile-$lockedfilename
    start_server
}
```

Many interrupts could be sumarized or ignored at main loop, but processing have to be done at main level only.

There is a little demo about what's wrong:

> ***window1***

```
trap "echo USR2 sleep 4;sleep 4" USR2
while :;do printf "\r%s " $(date +%s%N);sleep .333;done
1361606565xxxxxxxxx
```

( `xxxxxxxxx` changing 3x / second)

> ***window2***

```
for ((i=5;i--;));do echo KILL;kill -USR2 5187;sleep .5;done
KILL
KILL
KILL
KILL
KILL

1361606722582175969 USR2 sleep 4
USR2 sleep 4
1361606770xxxxxxxxx
```

Only two interrupts over five was trapped across my loop.

If you search an explanation: 5 x 0,5 = 2,5 seconds. It is far less than 4 seconds sleep, so why did I recieve a second interrupt, but not all five??

#### Untrap at main loop

There is a little trick for untrapping at main loop:

```
while [ "$SERVER_PID" ];do 
    wait $SERVER_PID

    OLDIFS="$IFS" IFS=$'\n'
    TRAPS=($(trap))                            # save traps
    IFS="$OLDIFS"
    eval "$(printf "trap -- %s\n" ${TRAPS[@]##*\'})"  # untrap

    case "$CMD_TRAP" in
        refresh   ) refresh_server   ;;
        terminate ) terminate_server ;;
        *         ) refresh_server   ;;        # in case server just end.
      esac;
    CMD_TRAP=""
    if [ "$SERVER_PID" ]
    then echo "LOOP."
    else echo "EXIT."

        eval "$(printf "%s\n" "${TRAPS[@]}")"      # restore traps
    fi
  done
```

Comment: yes, I did. I adopted the flagging method in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a tail-recursive start_server, with only minor changes to your code. (removed one line and added three lines containing `HUPPED`)

```
HUPPED=false
SERVER_PID=""

start_server() {
    npm start &
    SERVER_PID=$!
    wait $SERVER_PID
    if $HUPPED; then HUPPED=false; start_server; fi
}
terminate_server() {
    [ ! "xSERVER_PID" = "X" ] && kill -SIGTERM $SERVER_PID
    SERVER_PID=""
}
refresh_server() {
    HUPPED=true
    terminate_server
    #start_server
}

trap refresh_server SIGHUP
start_server
```